# How would I go about investigating and resolving a Mercurial authorization problem?

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, dvcs

I have a private repository with bitbucket.

I'm using Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 0.9.3) on Ubuntu.

When I try to clone my repository, I'm prompted for my username and password which I enter correctly.

as a result i get: `abort: authorization failed`

This works perfectly fine from windows.

I just want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious before I submit a bug.

I'm new to distributed version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a fairly old version of mercurial at this point.  Can you install 1.0.2 and see if that works?

I clone remotely over http and over ssh all the time without any authorization problems.  This is a very common use case and I'd be surprised if it were a bug that weren't fixed pretty quickly in one of the later releases.